# How to send data $_POST from AJAX to controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm creating an application with Codeigniter MVC, but I have problem with send data from AJAX post to my controller. I got error like this:

> ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer LINE 3: WHERE "nip" = 0 ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type cast

Model code:

```
// model m_members
    function get_name($nip)
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $this->db->select('name');
        $this->db->where('nip', $nip);
        return $this->db->get('student')->result_array();
    }
```

Controller:

```
function insert_member()
{
    $this->load->model('m_members');
    $data['type'] = $this->m_members->type_member(); //another function
    $nip = $this->input->post('nip');
    $data = $this->m_members->get_name($nip);
    echo json_encode($data);

    $this->load->view('add_members',$data); 

}
```

View:

```
// view
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username*">
<input type="text" id="name" name="username" placeholder="Name *">
```

My JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#username").keyup(function() {
        var nip = $('#username').val();
        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            data    : "nip="+nip,
            url     : "add_members/insert_member",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
            $("#name").val(data.name);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

and this my table

```
//my table
nip  | name  | address
--------------------------
1212 | David | 1428 Hannah Street
--------------------------
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please change your data code in ajax :

data    : "nip="+nip,

with

data    : {nip:nip},

Comment: still got error "Error Number:

ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer LINE 3: WHERE "nip" = 0 ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

SELECT "name" FROM "student" WHERE "nip" = 0

Filename: E:\xampp\htdocs\student\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 331

Comment: You are calling ajax on keyup function which will call insert_member on each key press and pass one by one alphabet .I think you want to pass complete username in ajax and then want to match it from ajax function,so you can call onchange instead keyup.

Also,in insert_member, echo $this->input->post('nip'); and check what you getting if above criteria is not what you need.

Comment: @dogol, it looks like the `where` needs a string, but you are passing an integer. Try passing `(string) $nip` instead in your PHP controller. I don't know CI though - make sure it does escaping/binding for you, to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: SOLVED :D ty all for your respons

Comment: @dogol what was the exact issue ? if you can share?